# REST Producer Connector for Kafka Stream

Tags: rest, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a web server which receives some events as post request , I want to process using Kafka Streams. Which Source connector can I use to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

A Source Connector reads data from a source (your server, in this case), which would be GET requests...

If you want POST requests from Connect (consuming Kafka then sending requests), that would be a Sink Connector, and has nothing to do with Kafka Streams

relevant: https://github.com/llofberg/kafka-connect-rest

If that doesn't meet your needs, you can write your own Connector

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer for pointing out, I am new to Kafka, May be I should some more background of my need. I have a HTTP service which receives the events as POST request and I need to push these events to Kafka and then process them using Kafka streams and sink it to S3. So which type of source connector should I use ?

Comment: You wouldn't. You would put a Kafka producer and Streams application directly into your web service